# Is 'dxsdkver.h' header file missing from the Windows SDK as of 8 and 8.1?

Tags: winapi, windows-8, directx, sdl

I'm trying to compile SDL2 from the latest stable release (2.0.0). The build fails on Windows 8 in Visual Studio 2012 because of missing DirectX headers, specifically `dxsdkver.h`. I know that Microsoft merged the DirectX and Windows SDKs together in Windows 8, but I can't find this header anywhere in the Windows 8 or Windows 8.1 SDKs. However, I can find it in the old June 2010 DirectX SDK.

Is there a replacement for this header or has it been moved/renamed in the new Windows 8 SDKs? Or should I just continue to build against the old DirectX SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing the dxsdkver header file does is #define some macros to the installed version of the DXSDK.  If SDL2 requires this header, it looks like it may have some compile-time dependencies on different versions.  In fact, looking at some snips from the code, one example is that SDL compiles without XAUDIO2 support if your SDK is older than a particular version.  Until SDL2 is updated to target the Windows SDK, your safest bet is to build it against the latest DirectX SDK (June 2010).

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if these macros have been moved to somewhere else in the Windows SDK?

Comment: I don't think so - no hits for any of the macros in my 8.1 SDK Include directory (`_DXSDK_PRODUCT_MAJOR`, `_DXSDK_PRODUCT_MINOR`, `_DXSDK_BUILD_MAJOR`, `_DXSDK_BUILD_MINOR`).

Answer (score 1):

The latest SDL version from official Mercurial repository http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL compiles well on Windows 8. I recommend to use it instead of installing old DirectX SDK.